# MySQL query does count then display additional data

Tags: mysql, sql

This current query works great and gives me a count of how many times and office occurs in the table for each record and the office name.  How do I expand this query to first display the Office and Count like it currently does and THEN displays colums lastName, Phone underneath the count of each record that matched the Office and then moves onto the next Office and Office(Count) and displays those lastname, Phone records and so forth?  Is that possible in MySQL?

```
SELECT Office, COUNT(Office) AS c 
FROM Active 
GROUP BY Office 
HAVING COUNT(Office) >= 5  ORDER BY c DESC
```

Example:

Office1 | 2

Office1 | lastName | Phone

Office1 | lastName | Phone

Office2 | 3

Office2 | lastName | Phone

Office2 | lastName | Phone

Office2 | lastName | Phone

Comment: It's relative...for me it's extremely advanced ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that. Your best bet would be `UNION`, but you must have identical number of columns and column types, which doesn't match your criteria.

Why don't you try

```
SELECT Office, lastName, Phone FROM Active ORDER BY Office
```

and in your programming language, parse the rows and use a counter variable to count identical `Office` records, and build your own table.

Edit: You say it's for exporting directly to a spreadsheet. You could do this in two queries: Do your count() query, and then do the query I have above. Export the two results and mix them in a spreadsheet as you need. Hey, it gets the job done.

Comment: But MySQL is the programming launguage, I plan to go direct to export with this data for import into a spreadsheet, not for display on the web.

Comment: Gotchya. Well basically, my answer is no you can't do it lol.

Comment: LOL...we'll see, hoping you are wrong ;-)  SQL is pretty powerful in the right hands (just not mine).

Comment: The number/type of columns must be match in your query, and your expected results don't, so you can't do it (to my knowledge >_<). You could do it in two queries though.. Do your count() query, and then do the query I have in my answer, and mix them in the spreadsheet as you need ;)

Comment: LOL...so excel becomes my programming language.  fair enough, I can work it that way.  thanks for helping me sort it out :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use MySQL's [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html), but the number of the columns, and the column names would have to be identical.

Overall this seems like a wrong approach. Try rethinking your logic where you don't need this sort of output.

I would suggest receiving just the lastname and phone, and caching the results, then parsing them. The COUNT(*) is technically redundant information since the number of rows with identical Office already describes that.

Comment: I need the count so that I can ORDER BY and display those with the largest count first, I really don't need to display it as long as its is ORDER BY correctly but it's a nice reference.

Comment: Do it in two queries. One gets the order, the other one gets everyones office ID, name, and phone. While displaying - loop through the Ordered query, but process the users.

Comment: Can you provide me a sample, I'm struggling with how to even start doing that?

Comment: Based on your comment to another answer - you say you don't want to parse the results before storing them. This makes it quite unfeasible. I strongly recommend intermediate parsing. Not just for the power of manipulation but for speed.

Comment: How about this...I have another table called Listing that also contains Office, LastName and Phone...is is possible to perform a UNION to show this data after the count?  I know it may not be efficient but I'll need to only run it quarterly.